# jQuery-ui selectable div and open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-selectable

I have divs, for select div I used jquery-ui selectable, I want to click on the div(clicked div drawing) and the modal is opened.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="selectable" class="right-content">
    <div id="selectable" class="clickable row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 table-bordered">1</div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="col-lg-2 table-bordered">2</div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="col-lg-2 table-bordered">3</div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="col-lg-2 table-bordered">4</div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="col-lg-2 table-bordered">5</div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="col-lg-1 table-bordered">6</div>
    </div>
    <div id="orderModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h3>Order</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body"></div>
      <div id="orderItems" class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $( function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable();
 });
```

Comment: What to open a modal in click on the div(clicked div drawing) ?? What's div drawing?

Comment: I click on the div, then modal will open and selected div will paint(square).

Comment: I want to do like google calendar,